# Laravel eloquent where condition in with model (Constraining Eager Loads) not working

Tags: php, laravel

Here is My Controller's Code to get Order list with Condition apply in join table

```
$orders = Order::whereHas('order_carpets', function($q){
            $q->where('carpent_no', '1345');
        })->get();
```

Model Code looks something like this

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'orders';
    public function order_carpets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order_carpet::class, 'orders', 'id', 'order_carpet_id');
    }

    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class, 'orders', 'id', 'customer_id');
    }
}

class Order_carpet extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

The result I'm getting now is all data of table Order

Comment: do toSql() instead of get() and see what query gets generated.

Comment: select * from `orders` where exists (select * from `order_carpets` inner join `orders` on `order_carpets`.`id` = `orders`.`order_carpet_id` where `orders`.`id` = `orders`.`id` and `carpet_no` = ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `orders` table appears in your main query and your subquery, without aliases.
So `where orders.id = orders.id` refers to the same table twice and so is always true.

The problem is the `order_carpets` relationship. It's actually a `BelongsTo` relationship:

```
public function order_carpets()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order_carpet::class, 'order_carpet_id');
}
```

The same goes for the `customers` relationship:

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id');
}
```

You should probably rename them to `order_carpet` and `customer`.

Comment: still showing toSql() query as
select * from `orders` where exists (select * from `order_carpets` where `orders`.`order_carpet_id` = `order_carpets`.`id` and `carpet_no` = ?)